# How to display the updated element in javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript issue. Suppose I have an input box that the user can enter the values and I store them in an array and display the array. Values like:

```
apple 8, orange 4, pear 10, orange 3.
```

What I want to do is to show the latest updated added value so when the user wants to see the values they see which is (all values in the array plus the latest updated value) so I dont want to show orange 4! I want to show orange 3 instead.

```
apple 8, pear 10, orange 3. //numbers are quantity of fruits that I randomly set
```

So the orange with the quantity of 4 is replaced y the orange with quantity of 3. This is my code for creating array, I think I should use key value store or hash instead, to display the last updated value, can you give me any hint? Thanks

```
this.fruitArray.push(inputData);
this.fruitArray = this.removeDuplicate(this.fruitArray);
if(inputData !== "" ){
      $('#displayBox').html(this.fruitArray);
}

removeDuplicate: function(Arr){
                var cur, found;
                for (i = Arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    cur = Arr[i];
                    found = false;
                    for (j = i - 1; !found && j >= 0; j--) {
                        if (cur === Arr[j]) {
                            if (i !== j) {
                                Arr.splice(i, 1);
                            }
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return Arr;
            },
```

Comment: use Array's pop function to get only the last entered value in that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want access to the last element of an array, you can do it like this:

```
var lastElement = myArray[myArray.length-1]
```

in your case:

```
$('#displayBox').html(fruitArray[fruitArray.length -1]);
```

example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GyKb6/2/)

--EDIT---------------------------

Still not sure of what you try to achieve, but could you just store the last fruit update in an other variable ?

```
var fruitArray = [];
var lastFruitUpdate = "";
```

....

```
if(inputData !== "" ){
    lastFruitUpdate = inputData;
    if(fruitArray[inputData] != undefined){
        fruitArray[inputData]++;
    }else{
        fruitArray[inputData] = 1;
    }
    $('#displayBox').html(lastFruitUpdate+"( "+fruitArray[lastFruitUpdate]+")");        
}
```

example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GyKb6/7/)

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I want to see the latest updated value. not the alst value

Comment: i try to understand, when a user type "orange" you increment the orange count ?

Comment: I really appreciate the answers. but When I click "save" in your fiddle I want to see all the added element plus the last updated element for the duplicated values. for example, I enter, Apple 1, Orange 3, pear 10, orange 4. After clicking save I want to see Apple 1, pear 10, orange 4. So the orange with the quantity of 4 is replaced y the orange with quantity of 3. (Numbers are the amount of the fruits that I randomly gave)

Comment: Hi again, what if the format for entering data is like: data.set value_1 50, data.set value_2 100. I could not change your code to take care of this format. Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: when you use `.split(" ")` on your string result it will split your string based on the space charactere and return it in an array so now if you just need value_1 and 50 but not data.set just access the next value in the array no? `fruit[1]` & `fruit[2]`

Comment: Hi again! i have another question. suppose some one enters apple 8, apple 4 and again apple 8! but it always shows the value 4 for apple! Since is 8 is repeated and it only see apple 4! how can I update with the latest value?

Comment: and one other thing regarding my yesterday question. How can I validate that the user enters value in this format: data.set value_1 50. I only care about (data.set). If there is no (data.set) at the beginning I dont want it to get saved in the array. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want last element of array which is just added into array, then use below statement.

```
this.fruitArray.push[this.fruitArray.length-1]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I want to see the latest updated value. not the alst value